# Quartz 2D Layers

Tags: objective-c, iphone, quartz-2d

I want to create 2 separate layers using quartz 2D. Can i handle there redraw methods separately? so that i can redraw 1 layer without redrawing the whole screen or other layers.

Is it possible? any code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and easy to do. Use the QuartzViewController/QuartzView classes in Apple's QuartzDemo iPhone sample code to get started. Use subclasses if you want specialized behavior.

See here:

http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from the Mac world. On the Mac, you'd create two overlapping views and deal with it that way. On the iPhone, I suspect you do the same: create two UIViews and then handle the two redraw methods independently. I believe overlapping views are fine on the iPhone (just as they are now on the Mac since 10.5).

Comment: for both views drawRect will be separate? how to deal with it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Just create two classes that have different drawRect methods (doing whatever you want) and then stick one instance of each into your Interface Builder file.